# <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /> Where it should be place in <head>to render doucment as IE7 properly in IE8?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, cross-browser

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />` Where it should be place in `<head>` to render document as IE7 properly in IE8?

Comment: There's not a lot of choice. Surely, it depends what else you have in your <head>

Comment: It's a valid question, placement can be important for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as this meta tag changes the way the document is rendered, and could cause visual changes, I would apply the same rule as that for the `content-type` header, which is 
**as early in the `<head>` as possible**.

From the W3C [**encoding specs**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html):

> The META declaration must only be used when the character encoding is organized such that ASCII-valued bytes stand for ASCII characters (at least until the META element is parsed). **META declarations should appear as early as possible in the HEAD element.**

Comment: what is the benefit to put content-type as earlt as possible?

Comment: The content-type determines how the characters in the web site are rendered. If the server does not send a content-type header, the browser has to rely on the `<meta>` tag. So it could be that it has to switch encodings to the value specified by the meta tag *while it is already rendering the page*. If the meta tag is built in late,  it could be that the switch in encodings becomes visible to the user's eye.

Comment: how can i know my server is content-type header or not andi f my server is sending then should i not use <mtea> again?

Comment: Check the headers your server sends, for example using Firebug or the Web Developer Toolbar.

Comment: and in site's view source " <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />" is also there.

Comment: and server header has "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"

Comment: The server header will do, but the meta tag won't hurt (as long as it's identical with what's in the header).

Comment: but is there any type of benefit to keep in <head> also ? not confirm buti think w3c validation will give error if <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> will not be present in document.

Answer (score 1):

In the document's `head`, where the other `meta` tags are, after `<meta http-equiv="content-type" ...>`.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere within the `<head>` element.

You can also send it directly as an HTTP header if you choose to. For a complete site it may make sense just to configure the server to send out this additional header than touching each and every file.